# what is the efficient method to check an array contains duplicate values in php?

Tags: php, arrays

what is the efficient method to check an array contains duplicate values?
I have an array which contains emails. I want to know whether there is any email-id repeating.

**Update:** I am not interested in the repeating values. I want to know whether "It contains duplicate value" or "It doesn't contain duplicate value".

Comment: Show your code. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Rikesh The code In my mind is compare each value to other values in the array. Just like selection sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (count(array_unique($arr)) == count($arr)) 
  echo "Array does not contain duplicate elements"; 
else
  echo "Array contains duplicate elements";
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way that should be quite efficient is to make the array unique, and then compare it to the original array to see if any elements have been removed:

```
count(array_unique($emails)) == count($emails)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i extract duplicate values from an array

```
  <?php
function array_not_unique( $a = array() )
{
  return array_diff_key( $a , array_unique( $a ) );
}
?>
```

It returns the duplicate entries. It's the most simple and efficient way.

As you edited your post, the most efficient way to only know that it has duplicate or not is the way that most suggest.

count(array_unique($array)) == count($array)

Answer (score 1):

If any one want case insensitive array unique value then try below

```
function array_iunique($array) {

return array_intersect_key($array,array_unique(
                array_map('strtolower',$array) ) );
}
```

---

```
$array[1] = "test@google.com";
$array[2] = "test@hotmail.com";
$array[3] = "TEST@google.com";
$array[4] = "Test@hotmail.com";

//print_r(array_unique($array));

print_r(array_iunique($array));
```

// result  Array ( [1] => test@google.com [2] => test@hotmail.com )

Answer (score 0):

You should use `array_count_values()` method to find number of occurrence of elements. It's easy and efficient method.

```
$array = array('a', 'o', 'p', 'b', 'a', 'p', 'k', 'k', 'k');

print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

output

```
Array
(
   [a] => 2
   [o] => 1
   [p] => 2
   etc...
)
```